# Two rewrite rules in the same htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

In the www root folder of my web server I have 2 folders for 2 differents websites

```
www/firstsite
www/secondsite
```

To reach the index.php file of the first site I go to  `www.firstsite.com/firstProject`

To reach the index.php file of the second website I go to  `www.secondsite.com/secondProject`

I would like to put an unique htaccess file in the root folder "www". This htaccess file would have a rewriterule for both webstie.

So users would see `www.firstsite.com` instead of `www.firstsite.com/firstProject`

and `www.secondsite.com` instead of `www.secondsite.com/secondProject`

Edit: I use this htaccess to rewrite the url of `www.firstsite.com`(don't forget this website is located in folder `www/firstsite`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ firstsite/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Edite: here is the answer thank you to hjpotter92 !

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?firstsite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/firstProject [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /firstProject/$1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?secondsite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/secondProject [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /secondProject/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Do you not have access to apache's root server config? Or VHost config?

Comment: No I don't have access on vhost. Is it possible to do it with htaccess file ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but using root config/vhost would make the server perform a lot faster. :)

Comment: Ok thank you for the tip. I have edited my question to show wich htaccess file I'm using to rewrite the url of the first site and I would like to do the same for the second site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable to test your domain name, and redirect based on that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?firstsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/firstProject [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /firstProject/$1 [L]
```

similar rules will go for your second domain.

Comment: Thank you I have edited my question to show which rules I'm using to rewrite the url of www.first.com.

I try to implement your answer and I'll give a feedback when I can

Comment: Thanks my friend it works ! Here is the final htaccess I use:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?firstsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/firstProject [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /firstProject/$1 [L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?secondsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/secondProject [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /secondProject/$1 [L]

Comment: @zm455 The `RewriteEngine On` is not required the second time.